# Push the value of button or Link to DE

Tags: email, dataextensions, confirmation

Good day,
I need to create email with two buttons or links "Confirm" an "Cancel".
When user clicks on it, the Status field in DE should change its value on "Confirmed" or "Canceled".
Can I create such function with the help of Ampscript?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple code-free solution, the suggestion would be to use Journey Builder.

Use whatever schedule is appropriate for your use case, then:

1. Send email activity (for your email with the two buttons)
2. Wait period (probably makes sense to make this long enough after the email has been sent to catch all the responses)
3. Engagement split - this will allow you to create different paths for those who click on Confirmed vs those who click on Canceled (select individual link clicks to determine the path)
4. Add an 'update contact' activity to each path, updating the field in the Status field in data extension accordingly

There are other ways to do this - AMPscript (most often via an intermediary Cloud page) or you could use SQL to query the _click system data view for clickers of a specific link before writing them to a data extension (this could run via Automation Studio and would provide greater accuracy, for example in the scenario where someone clicks the 'Confirmed' link one day then clicks the 'Canceled' link the following day, you'll be writing the latest value).

Comment: Good day! Thank you, your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem at all - glad to help!